# adobe air CameraUi behaving differently on different android devices

Tags: android, actionscript-3, video, air, android-camera

I am building an app that has to access the camera, take a video and access the video in the app and play it back. I also need to add an overlay while recording the video. I tested my code on 3 android devices huawei ascend g300 , nexus 7 and galaxey S3 and it behaved differently on each.

On the huawei (only has camera on back) it behaved as I wanted. only recorded video and camera ui closed after video was shot.

on the nexus 7(only has front facing camera) the camera UI displayed for a second and then I get the following message `unfortunately gallery has stopped`

on the sg s4 (has camera on front and back) the camera ui launches takes the video but does not return to my app.

bellow is my accessCamera Class:

```
package Classes {
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.media.*;
    import flash.media.Camera;
    import flash.media.CameraUI;
    import flash.events.MediaEvent;
    import flash.net.*;
    public class AccessCamera extends MovieClip {
        //-------------- CameraUI-----------------------//
        public static var ui = new CameraUI();
        public static var video = new Video();
        //------------- end Camera UI------------------//

        public function AccessCamera() {
        // constructor code
        trace ("access camera class accessed");
        }
        public function loggedIn(){         
            //------------cmaera UI---------------//
            if ( CameraUI.isSupported){
                ui.launch(MediaType.VIDEO);
        ui.addEventListener(MediaEvent.COMPLETE,UICompleteHandler);
            }
        }
        public function UICompleteHandler(event:MediaEvent):void{
            var media:MediaPromise = event.data;
            trace(media.file.url  + " - " + media.relativePath + " - " +media.mediaType);
            parent.addChild(video);
            var conn:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
            conn.connect(null);
            //attach a stream  to the video-object
            var stream:NetStream = new NetStream(conn);
            video.attachNetStream(stream);
            stream.client = new MobileClient();
            //play the stream
            stream.play(media.file.url);
        }
    }
}
//------------- end of package -------------//
class MobileClient {
    public function onMetaData(info:Object):void {
        trace("metadata: duration=" + info.duration + " width=" + info.width + " height=" + info.height + " framerate=" + info.framerate);
    }
    public function onCuePoint(info:Object):void {
        trace("cuepoint: time=" + info.time + " name=" + info.name + " type=" + info.type);
    }
}
```

Any clues on why its behaving so differently on different devices.

Comment: What are the devices os version? it may be Adobe Air bug with a specific android version.

Comment: huawei 4.0 , galaxey S3 4.3 and nexus 7 4.4

Comment: I think it is working correctly with 4.0 and has a bug with 4.3 & 4.4, i suggest to file a bug on Adobe site here (https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm).